# ng-repeat multile fileds with multiple name like append

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am newly working on angularjs. Currently I will be working on Add more button with ng-repeat. I want to click bootstrap add more than generate div and div have three input fields 1. name, 2. description, 3. file but my code not to repeat properly please help me.

```
Controller:
// Add More Step Function

$scope.step = { fields: [] };
    $scope.addFormField = function() {
    $scope.step.fields.push('');
}  

Html Code: 

<div ng-repeat="field in step.fields track by $index">
                        <div id="div{{6+$index}}">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="process.process.step.name5" placeholder="Step Name">-->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='process.process.step.fields[$index]' placeholder="Step Name">

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="process.process.step.description5" placeholder="Step Description">-->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model='process.process.step.fields[$index]' placeholder="Step Description">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <!--<input data-my-Directive class="form-control" type="file" id="file5" name="file5" ng-click="uploadFile('file5');" />-->
                                <input data-my-Directive class="form-control" type="file" id="file{{6+$index}}" name="file{{$index}}" ng-click="uploadFile('file{{$index}}');" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="{{imageName}}" ng-model="process.process.step.file"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle or plunker ?

Comment: No I am working on localhost. I am not to be able this code create to fiddle or plunker sorry :(

Comment: Please See this URL : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0245fcck91

Comment: what is you angular version???

Comment: I have done something similar and sharing you at http://jsfiddle.net/w0037yr9/1/

Comment: My angular version is 1.3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the demo code:: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Upal_Roy/o4yge3cv/)

Change your version to (minimum of) 1.2 and it will work, since `track by $index` was introduced in that version.

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.step = { fields: [] };


    $scope.addFormField = function() {
   $scope.step.fields.push({});
} 
});
```